# is there a cross device CNContact identifier?

Tags: ios, cncontact

Is there any icloud identifier for a CNContact that I could persist and reuse across devices ?

The idea would be to be able to pull that CNContact again from a different iOS device.

Documentation doesn't say anything about that. I know the previous ABAddressbook framework didn't have that either but I'm hoping apple might have something cooking for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked an Apple rep at the 2016 WWDC conference and the answer is NO.
at least not at the moment. they might have something for this in the future but for now you will have to make sure match the CNContact identifier you stashed against the local store to be sure its the same contact.

Answer (score 2):

per the documentation

> Note that this identifier only uniquely identifies the contact on the current device.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontact/1403103-identifier